# I cannot calculate date more than 5 years ahead?

Tags: php

I need to show a message if the end date is before the start date.

The code is working, but if I put the end date more than 5 years before the start date. The code did nothing.

I donot know way. that's weird?

Here is my code

```
         if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
        {
            $startdate  = $_POST['start'];

        $enddate=$_POST['end'];
    if(abs(strtotime($enddate ) < strtotime($startdate)))
          {

        ?>
  <table width="767" border="0">
    <tr>
      <th bordercolor="#CC3300" bgcolor="#CC0000" scope="row"><div align="left"><span class="style11 style3">Warring:</span></div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="761" bordercolor="#CC3300" bgcolor="#CC0000" scope="row"><div align="left" class="style3 style11">The end date you entered is before the start date!!</div></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <?php
      }
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: What values are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry,what you mean?

Comment: 5 years is a long time, it's probably enough ?

Comment: What are the values for `$_POST['start']` and `$_POST['end']`?

Comment: I need to calculate until 2060 that's mean no end date

Comment: All we see is `$_POST['end']`, what are you really posting, what's the string you're typing in the form

Comment: No End Date=2060-08-27 and Fall 2014=2014-08-27

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) does not support dates after 19 Jan 2038 due to the [2038 date problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC

`DateTime()` can work around it, though.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $startdate  = new DateTime($_POST['start']);
    $enddate    = new DateTime($_POST['end']);
    if($enddate < $startdate) {
```

Comment: Is that when the world ends, 19. January 2038 ?

Comment: Yes, that's when we run out of coffee

Comment: Oh God, I have to prepare, bombshelters to build and whatnot. Thank you for letting me know, +1 !

Comment: I got this now, because I use the dates also to query the table: Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: It is working now, I used datatime for the message and for the query I used regular _POST thank you very much (: